# List of HDMI States (tvservice --state)

Tags: raspbian, hdmi

Is there an overview for all the HDMI states?

Because I'm getting different ones but, don't know

e.g:

```
tvservice -s
state 0x40009 [HDMI CEA (16) RGB lim 16:9], 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
..
tvservice -s
state 0x4000a [HDMI CEA (16) RGB lim 16:9], 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd presume these correspond to the CEA modes from here:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt/video.md#hdmi_mode

Although the state ID is not specified, your output matches "HDMI CEA (16)"  as 1080p @ 60 Hz.

Note there are two lists there, the first one is for when using CEA (predominantly TV) modes and the other for DMT (more appropriate to computer monitors).